# use multiple post method in a single nodejs file

Tags: node.js

this is my nodejs code

I've created a small express server using Nodejs and I'm currently able to handle a single post request - to check if a user exists or not.

I need to incorporate an additional post request, which would allow me to login a new user. The login request comes from a  login_page. HTML page which includes a same login form as first one.

the first post method in executing correctly but there no response from 2nd post method

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const encoder = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true});

const app = express();

// Serve static files from the "assets" folder
app.use("/assets", express.static("assets"));

// Set the view engine to "ejs"
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// Serve the login_styles.css file from the "css" folder
app.use("/login_styles", express.static(__dirname + "/css"));

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "GNAP9#ag",
    database: "dbmsclassroom"
});

// Connect to the database
connection.connect(function(error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error); // Print the error message
    } else {
        console.log("Connected to the database successfully!");
    }
});

// Serve the login page
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/Login_page.html");
});

// Handle the student login form submission
app.post("/student", encoder, function(req, res) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE user_id = ? AND password = ?", [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
        if (results.length > 0) {
            res.redirect("/welcomestudent");
        } else {
            res.redirect("/");
        }
    });
});

// Handle the teacher login form submission
app.post("/teacher", encoder, function(req, res) {
    var username1 = req.body.username1;
    var password1 = req.body.password1;
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE user_id = ? AND password = ?", [username1, password1], function(error, results, fields) {
        if (results.length > 0) {
            res.redirect("/welcometeacher");
        } else {
            res.redirect("/");
        }
    });
});

// Serve the student welcome page
app.get("/welcomestudent", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/welcomestudent.html");
});

// Serve the teacher welcome page
app.get("/welcometeacher", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/welcometeacher.html");
});

// Start the server and listen on port 4000
app.listen(4000, function() {
    console.log("Server listening on port 4000");
});
```

what changes must I

do so that 2nd post method also works properly.

i have referred some other examples , but all are same as my code

Comment: If it's nodejs, tag it as nodejs, not html.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are querying the students' table instead of whatever table you defined for teachers.

```
app.post("/teacher", encoder, function(req, res) {
    var username1 = req.body.username1;
    var password1 = req.body.password1;
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE user_id = ? AND password = ?", [username1, password1], function(error, results, fields) {
        if (results.length > 0) {
            res.redirect("/welcometeacher");
        } else {
            res.redirect("/");
        }
    });
})
```

You need to modify your query to the correct table, if you test your current /teacher post endpoint with a student details that exist, it would work.
So all you need to do is modify your query to match the correct table.

Comment: yups, its return empty array as the result. So then it redirect to `/` instead of `welcometeacher`.

Comment: table name was not a problem because  when i entered the correct credentials of the user(supposed to be of students table in the second post method)  , my page didn't redirect according to the code , even i  tried by changing the table  (creating a new table teachers and changing in the code of 2nd post method  )   but didn't work.